# Styling image maps with CSS/Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, dictionary

So, I had this idea the other day about making a banner of some sort that you could click on using image maps. Is it possible to change specific css properties when a part of the map is hovered on. I was thinking of different pictures zooming with a slight blur or something. I know that `<map>` and `<area>` are just points on which the user can click on, but is there a workaround that limitation ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use transparent divs inside your banner, with absolute positions and uniques IDs... And then, you use CSS for those IDs:hover.

Does it make sense to you?